# setState not updating variable when declared on initState

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have run into an issue with Flutter: I have a `navbar` which, depending on the item selected, returns me an integer number called Index. This index is then passed through a List to get the content of the body of the Scaffold, an object of `Widget()` class.

The default body is an object of `HomePage()`, that has an integer parameter called `rpm`. By default, the `HomePage()` should be the body displayed, so, as it depends on the `rpm` parameter, I declare the `rpm` parameter on the `initState`. I also have a `setState` that changes dynamically the `rpm`.

The weird thing is: if I declare the `List<Widgets> bodyList` in the initState, the `setState` doesn't seem to work. However, if I declare `List<Widgets> bodyList` in the build method, I can see the content of the `HomePage()` change dynamically with the `rpm`.

An excerpt of the code. Not working:

```
class _ScreenTreeState extends State<ScreenTree> {
  int _index;
  int _rpm;
  List<Widget> bodyList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isPlaying = false;
    _rpm = 0;
    _index = 0;
    bodyList = [
      HomePage(rpm: _rpm),
      StatisticsScreen(),
      WeightScreen(),
      SettingsPage()
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...
```

Working:

```
class _ScreenTreeState extends State<ScreenTree> {
  int _index;
  int _rpm;
  List<Widget> bodyList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isPlaying = false;
    _rpm = 0;
    _index =
        0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bodyList = [
      HomePage(rpm: _rpm),
      StatisticsScreen(),
      WeightScreen(),
      SettingsPage()
    ];
    
    return Scaffold(...
```

My theory is that this may have to do with the fact that if `_rpm` is declared as an integer, Dart reads it as a primitive and not as the object of an integer class, so if declared on the `initState`, I'm not actually passing an object, but a primitive. But I don't understand then why is it working when declared in the `build` method.

I feel this is irrelevant, but if somebody needs it, here it is the code that updates the value of `_rpm`. Please, don't read too much into this because I feel it is actually not relevant and may distract and confuse more than help:

```
onPressed: () {
          if (_isPlaying) {
            setState(() {
              _isPlaying = false;
            });
            Provider.of<MicrophoneEngine>(context, listen: false)
                .stopRecording();
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _isPlaying = true;
            });
            Provider.of<MicrophoneEngine>(context, listen: false)
                .startRecording((rpmCall) {
              setState(() {
                _rpm = rpmCall;
              });
            });
          }
        },
```

Comment: Don't store widgets in your state unless you really know what you're doing. Always make sure new widget objects are created for every call of `build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad practice to keep references for the widgets(like in the first example), in fact, you don't need that List at all.

Every time you use `setState`, you rebuild the widgets and you pass the new value. In the first example you pass the `HomePage(rpm: _rpm)` from the init every time, that's why it is not updated. Meaning, you don't rebuild `HomePage` with the updated value, you just passing the `HomePage` from the initState which was instantiated with the initial `_rpm` value of `0`.

Comment: Nice answer! However, it's not *necessarily* bad practice to store widgets in the state, but it often leads to confusion with beginners.

Comment: Imho there is absolutely no need to keep ref to a widget. He is not using List<Widget> inside the build, but he is using it in the initState, and that's the problem.

Comment: I perfectly understand what the issue is. But there is potential for performance advantages by storing widgets inside the state rather than instantiating new ones on rebuilds.

Comment: @YoBo So, If I'm getting it right, with `setState` only the variables inside the build method are rebuilt, right?. The variables in the initState will not be changed at all. Also, how would you change the content without the List? it seems the most straightforward thing to do to me.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks for your hindsight. Yes, I am a beginner. Also, while you may be right on the performance thing, is Flutter (or even Dart) suitable for the type of HPC scenarios where this would make sense?.

Comment: @aveon If you have a large and *complex* widget you could reduce the amount of time and memory it takes to execute rebuilds that involve that widget by reusing a stored one. It's not something to worry about unless you have performance issues.

Comment: @aveon `setState` is really just calling `build` again. What you put in `setState`'s callback has absolutely no effect. The variables in `initState` can absolutely be changed. But the `initState` function is only run once in the widget's lifetime. It's advisable to create methods in your state that generate the content of your List on each rebuild if you expect them to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help guys. I really appreciate it.